# Numerical Solving Code Go Faster (numpy/scipy)

Tags: python, numpy

I'd appreciate some help with how I could go about making my code go faster.  Currently, it really is simply too slow.  It basically generates two square waves, with varying dutycycles, then applies a special filter to it the generated square waves to extract a frequency component from the square waves, and tries to match that frequency component to a value by varying the dutycycles of the two square waves.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize, integrate, signal
import math
import cmath

PI = np.pi


def Goetrzel(x, target_frequency, sample_rate):
    s_prev = 0
    s_prev2 = 0
    normalized_frequency = target_frequency / sample_rate

    wr = np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * normalized_frequency)
    wi = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * normalized_frequency)

    coeff = 2.0 * wr
    for sample in x:
        s = sample + coeff * s_prev - s_prev2
        s_prev2 = s_prev
        s_prev = s

    XKreal = s_prev * wr - s_prev2
    XKimag = s_prev * wi

    XK = (XKreal + 1j*XKimag) / (len(x)/2.)

    #power = s_prev2 * s_prev2 + s_prev * s_prev - coeff * s_prev * s_prev2 ;
    return abs(XK), np.angle(XK)*180./PI


def equations(p, zcurr, z, k1, k2):
    P = lambda z, D1, D2: \
        signal.square(k1*z, duty=D1) * signal.square(k2*z, duty=D2)
    K12 = lambda z: -np.cos(np.pi/2.*z/L)+1.
    K32 = lambda z: -np.sin(np.pi/2.*z/L)+1.

    D1, D2 = p

    h = 0.01
    eq1 = Goetrzel(P(np.arange(0.,10.,h),D1,D2), k1/(2.*PI), 1./h)[0] - K12(zcurr)
    eq2 = Goetrzel(P(np.arange(0.,10.,h),D1,D2), k2/(2.*PI), 1./h)[0] - K32(zcurr)

    return eq1**2 + eq2**2


def DutyCycleSolver(z, k1, k2, display=False):
    D1 = np.empty([len(z)])
    D1.fill(np.nan)
    D2 = np.empty([len(z)])
    D2.fill(np.nan)
    Derr = np.empty([len(z)])
    Derr.fill(np.inf)
    D1_D2_guess = np.empty([len(z),2])

    for i in range(len(z)):
        solutionFound = False
        for guessD1 in np.arange(0.8, 1., 0.1):
            for guessD2 in np.arange(0.8, 1., 0.1):
                temp = optimize.fmin(equations,
                                     x0=(guessD1, guessD2),
                                     args=(z[i],z,k1,k2,),
                                     xtol=1e-6,
                                     ftol=1e-6,
                                     disp=False,
                                     full_output=True)
                if temp[0][0] < -1.e-8 or temp[0][1] < -1.e-8 or \
                   temp[0][0] > 1.+1.e-8 or temp[0][1] > 1.+1.e-8:
                    continue

                DerrCur = temp[1]
                if DerrCur <= 1.e-3:
                    D1[i], D2[i] = temp[0]
                    Derr[i] = temp[1]
                    D1_D2_guess[i] = [guessD1, guessD2]
                    solutionFound = True
                    break
                elif DerrCur > 1.e-3 and DerrCur < Derr[i]:
                    D1[i], D2[i] = temp[0]
                    Derr[i] = temp[1]
                    D1_D2_guess[i] = [guessD1, guessD2]

            if solutionFound is True:
                if display:
                    print 'Solution found at', z[i]
                    print 'Using:', D1[i], D2[i]
                    print 'Found with guess:', D1_D2_guess[i]
                    print 'Error:', Derr[i]
                    print
                break

        if solutionFound is False and display:
            print 'No solution found at', z[i]
            print 'Using:', D1[i], D2[i]
            print 'With guess:', D1_D2_guess[i]
            print 'Error:', Derr[i]
            print


h = 0.3
L = 2.e3
z = np.arange(0., L, h)

DutyCycleSolver(z, 3., 8., display=True)
```

Comment: Have you profiled to find the hotspots? Have you tried different min-finding algorithms? How slow is slow anyway?

Comment: Obvious improvement is by deleting the for-cycles. I haven't studied your code completely but it seems you are trying to play the role of the solver by supplementing different starting conditions and solving over and over again. Besides, you are defining stuff inside your objective function that ought to have an effect.

Comment: I would focus my attention on speeding up the `Goetrzel` function, and in particular the `sample` loop inside it.  There 3 outer loops, but they end up calling `optimize.fmin`.  That's fundamental barrier to 'vectorizing' those outer loops.

Answer (score 0):

This improve a bit bit bit(0.000001%?) of your code. So this is useless.

before:

```
DerrCur = temp[1]
if DerrCur <= 1.e-3:
    D1[i], D2[i] = temp[0]
    Derr[i] = temp[1]
    D1_D2_guess[i] = [guessD1, guessD2]
    solutionFound = True
    break
elif DerrCur > 1.e-3 and DerrCur < Derr[i]:
    D1[i], D2[i] = temp[0]
    Derr[i] = temp[1]
    D1_D2_guess[i] = [guessD1, guessD2]
```

after:

```
DerrCur = temp[1]
if DerrCur <= 1.e-3:
    D1[i], D2[i] = temp[0]
    Derr[i] = temp[1]
    D1_D2_guess[i] = [guessD1, guessD2]
    solutionFound = True
    break
elif DerrCur < Derr[i]:
    D1[i], D2[i] = temp[0]
    Derr[i] = temp[1]
    D1_D2_guess[i] = [guessD1, guessD2]
```

Apparently `temp = optimize.fmin(equations,,,` is the bottleneck. Vector operation was executed about 20*20*1000 = 400k times. It means if vector calc is about 1ms, you need 400 second to finish it.